# Pass the loss value to other models in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Assume I have two models in series with each other. I am using lstm for both. I want to have a prediction from one of them and find the loss between the predicted value and the ground truth and pass this number to update the other model. Can anyone tell me where to add external loss from outside into Keras model.

For example. Consider the loss between predicted and true value is 0.2.  I want to pass this 0.2 to another lstm keras model as an external value to add it with the loss from its output. [image]

What python command with  keras can do this and where should I add this loss to what module. I thought it should be added to model.compile but the loss there is for objective function. How can I take this loss into account for the next layer that it understands to account for it (in updating the parameters using SGD or any optimizer in training)

Comment: Is your goal to have model 1 predict the error of model 2 ? Simplest approach: train model 2, generate a set of predictions, measure error and use that as training data for model 1. If your goal is to have model1 contribute to the prediction of your task then the question is not well formulated. For instance you could have model1 and model2 generate predictions and then average then before computing the loss if you want both models to collaborate on the prediction.

Comment: Yes I need to pass the loss from model 1 to model 2. This means model 1 should contribute to the prediction of model 2. Assume there is some loss corresponding to first part how can I use this loss to update the next part. I need to make a decision sequentially therefore I should be able to pass the loss to make sure different models can adjust their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you are asking for isn't easily achieved (and perhaps isn't what you need).

Taking a step back, a training step in a keras model is roughly:

```py
predictions = model(train_x)
loss = some_loss_function(true_labels, predictions)
do_backprop_etc_to_update_model_in_order_to_minimize_loss(loss_operations)
```

keras & tf (cleverly) hides much of the implementation of the 3rd of these steps(which I have grossly oversimplified) but nonetheless it happens and is at the core of the training keras/tf does.

That means that if you have a loss from `model1` then it cannot sensibly be passed to `model2` without including the operations from `model1` **inside** `model2` (which is effectively just like having `model3` that does everything - including both outputs. This is, I expect, what you really want?)

If, instead of the architecture you have described, you opt for a single model then you can have 2 distinct outputs each with their own loss function. Furthermore your second loss function can be as complex as you like (so could include a computation of the first loss function).

An architecture like this is perhaps an example:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(17,))
dense1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
dense2 = Dense(18, activation='relu')(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(7, activation='relu')(dense2)
out1 = Softmax()(dense3)
out2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[out1,out2])
```

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 17)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           576         input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 18)           594         dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 7)            133         dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax_1 (Softmax)             (None, 7)            0           dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            19          dense_4[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,322
Trainable params: 1,322
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Thanks what I need is that model 2 takes into the account the loss from model 1 and use this loss along with its own loss to update the parameters. Assume my problem is sequential decision making and I need each model to adjust their parameters according to the loss corresponding to the last stage, otherwise errors will be accumulated as time passes.

Comment: The architecture I described does that. Your loss then becomes a combination (usually a sum but you can also weight each one) of `loss1` and `loss2` - parameters are updated to minimize this *combined* loss which is I think what you need

Comment: i think my last comment crossed with an edit you've made. I don't know what you mean by 'errors will be accumulated as time passes'

Comment: @user59419 If you want models to perform sequential decision making train them independently. i.e. train model2 taking as input the ground truth labels used to train model1.

Comment: I agree with @PedroMarques. It's either independent decision making (in which case it's independent training). Or you want the parameters for the layers in what you are calling model1 to depend on a combined loss. I think it's one or the other - I can't see a 3rd way thats half one and half the other.

Comment: @PedroMarques, yes that is what I am doing instead I am trying model 2 with the predicted value of model 1 and that is why I need to pass the loss.  Otherwise lets say you train model 1 and if you just pass the ground truth for model 1 to model 2 then why do you need the predicted value from model 1. What you are describing is more like a standard supervised learning.

Comment: @Stewart_R can you explain a little about your code. It does not look scalable since if we have 20 models we need to have 20 outputs. Also you method assumes model 1 and model 2 have the same input but what I am describing is that output of model 1 is fed to input of model 2.